# Can I mix DI and JNDI lookup when working with EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, jndi

I started learning EJB technology. My question was inspired by youtube guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NM61Xt7SGmk . It's kinda long so I will try to tell it short:

There are introduced two ways of working with EJB:

1. Manually creating javax.naming.InitialContext object, and after that, to obtain EJB use .lookup(String jndiPath) method for obtaining EJB instance.
2. Use dependency injection: Use annotation like @EJB, and let container for managing all those EJB references.

What if someone inconsistently use both of above methods in one application (.ear or .war)? Will context created manually (in the 1. point), and context created by container  (in the 2. point), be the same context? Can it cause unnecessarily duplicate EJB instances? Will it work in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part of your your question.

Many large projects sometimes do find themselves using both mechanism. This would normally happen when:

1. The application needs to access remote ejbs (probably running in a different server). The application will have to resort to manual lookup through the InitialContext
2. When the application defines its own ejbs, it would simply use EJB injection. However, doing a manual lookup here is equally allowed. The only reason is that its unnecessary, when you can let the container do it for you.
3. The EJB specs allows for Stateless EJB pooling, so that every request may be handled by a different ejb bean instance. If in your question you mean different instances, this could be the case. But also note that the injected object could (and mostly is) a proxy to the actual bean implementation. For Singleton beans, the container guarantees a single instance of the bean in the execution context, and hence whether you do a manual lookup or ejb injection, it will give you the same bean.
4. Stateful ejbs have states and a client session has to be maintained. Provided you are within the same client session a manual lookup or injection gives the same instance (Probably this part needs more clarification)

So to answer the last part of your question, there would not be any duplicates.